# Lightweight GCC for Alpine

Tags: docker, gcc, alpine-linux

Is there a lightweight GCC distribution that I can install in Alpine?

I am trying to make a small Docker image. For that reason, I am using Alpine as the base image (5MB). The standard GCC install dwarfs this in comparison (>100MB).

So is there a lightweight GCC distribution that I can install on Alpine?

Note: Clang is much worse (475MB last I checked).

Comment: What do you mean by "lightweight GCC distribution"? GCC is just a package (or some collection of them). And indeeds it takes several dozens of megabyte (on my Debian/Sid alone, its `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/cc1plus` is 25 megabytes, and you need much more to compile C++ code).

Comment: Do you really need gcc/clang, or would tcc for instance be good enough for you?

Comment: I had never heard of that. But I need c++, so i guess not.

Comment: Ok, please state your requirements more precisely in the question next time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There isn't such an image available, AFAIK, but you can make GCC slimmer by deleting unneeded GCC binaries.

It very much depends on what capabilities are required from GCC.

As a starting point, I'm assuming you need C support only, which means the `gcc` and `musl-dev` packages (for standard headers) are installed, which result with a ~100MB image with Alpine 3.8.

- If you don't need Objective-C support, you could remove `cc1obj`, which is the Objective-C backend. On Alpine 3.8, it would be located at `/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/6.4.0/cc1obj`, and takes up 17.6MB.
- If you don't need link time optimization (LTO), you could remove the LTO wrapper and main executables, `lto-wrapper` and `lto1`, which take up 700kb and 16.8MB respectively.
  While LTO optimization may be powerful, on most applications it's likely to result with only minor speed and size improvements (few percents). Plus, you have to opt-in for LTO, which is not done by most applications, so it may be a good candidate for removal.
- You could remove the Java front end, `gcj`, which doesn't seem to be working anyways. It is located at `/usr/bin/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl-gcj`, and weights 812kb.

By removing these, and squashing the resulting image, it would shrink into 64.4MB, which is still considerably large. You may be able to shrink further by removing additional files, but then you may loose some desired functionality and with a less appealing tradeoff.

Here's an example Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.8

RUN set -ex && \
    apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev

RUN set -ex && \
    rm -f /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/6.4.0/cc1obj && \
    rm -f /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/6.4.0/lto1 && \
    rm -f /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/6.4.0/lto-wrapper && \
    rm -f /usr/bin/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl-gcj
```

Tested using:
`sudo docker image build --squash -t alpine-gcc-minimal .`

Comment: Aha! I was already removing files like you are suggesting, but I didn't know about the docker squash command. Without that, the resulting docker files were still large because they had to include the layer with the full gcc...

Comment: This may be the direction I take.

Comment: @valiano I don't know for sure, but what worked for me is using the following
`RUN apk add --update --no-cache gcc>9.2.0-r3`
I think as I understand there is a problem with a certain version of GCC and AlpineLinux

Comment: Or just use multi-stage builds